# ng-options inside ng-repeat (with similar looking object) unexpected behavior, weird behavior

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

This is my first ever stackoverflow question therefore some help will be highly appreciated. I am working on an angular application where on one ui section, user is given a chance to multiple different choices which can be duplicate. e.g

A list of devices from the list. User can create multiple and they can even be all same types.

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrafaqi/dpLd85ep/5/

```
<table id="devices-table" class="table">
<tr ng-repeat="item in requiredDevices track by $index"  height="30">
    <td>
        <select 
            id="deviceList_{{$index}}"
            name="deviceList_name_{{$index}}"
            ng-model="item"
            ng-options="d.name for d in devices track by d.id"
            ng-change="deviceChanged($index, item)"
            >{{item}}
        </select>

        <div id="device-options" ng-show="item.id > -1">
            <label for="all_{{$index}}">1. Choose all</label><input     id="all_{{$index}}" type="radio" name="type_{{$index}}" value="1" ng-model="item.amountType" checked><br>
            <label for="some_{{$index}}">2. Choose some</label><input id="some_{{$index}}" type="radio" name="type_{{$index}}" value="2" ng-model="item.amountType" ><br>
            <label for="amount_{{$index}}">3. Choose amount</label><input id="amount_{{$index}}" type="radio" name="type_{{$index}}" value="3" ng-model="item.amountType" ><br>


      </div>
      <br>
  </td>
  </tr>

<tr id="add-device">
  <td>
  <br>
      <button id="add-device-button" ng-click="addDevice();">Add more</button>
      <button id="add-device-button" ng-click="showRequiredDevices();">Show required devices</button>
  </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

The corresponding javascript for this code is

```
var new_test_controller = app.controller('new_test_controller', function($scope) {
$scope.init = function() {
    $scope.current_customer = $scope.customers[0].first_name;

    $scope.addDevice();
};

$scope.test1_text = "";

$scope.customers = 
                [
                 { "uid": 1, "first_name": "Rizwan", "last_name": "Zia" },
                 { "uid": 2, "first_name": "Laura", "last_name": "Zia" },
                 { "uid": 3, "first_name": "Sara", "last_name": "Zia" },
                ];

$scope.devices = [
                    {"id" : 1, "name": "scissors", "amount": 3, "amountType": -1},
                    {"id" : 2, "name": "jumppapallo", "amount": 3, "amountType": -1},
                    {"id" : 3, "name": "gymstick", "amount": 3, "amountType": -1},
                 ];

$scope.requiredDevices = [

                ];

$scope.addDevice = function() {
    var device = new Object();

    device.tid = $scope.requiredDevices.length;
    device.id = -1;
    device.name = "";
    device.amount = 0;
    device.amountType = -1;

    console.log(device);
    $scope.requiredDevices.push(device);
};

$scope.showRequiredDevices = function() {
    console.log($scope.requiredDevices);
};

$scope.deviceChanged = function($index, item) {
    console.log('Device changed at index: ' + $index);
    console.log(item);
    //$scope.requiredDevices[$index] = item;
};

//console.log('Controller must have been initialized');
$scope.init();
});
```

Now, the problem is that I can't choose same devices with different attributes. To generate this behavior

1. Click add more button twice or more (create at least 2 devices)
2. Choose gymstick in first and second combo box
3. Choose any other device in third combo box
4. Now if you try to click radio button for gymstick, it will update the value of the other item as well which I do not want. It seems to be some behavior of angular. I tried to use $index (t.id was try to hack it). Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The problem is that your multiple of your `item` variables in the `ng-repeat` are assigned the same object from `devices` (with your `select`). I think you have confusion here between the type of devices (your `$scope.devices`) and the instance of a selected device (`$scope.requiredDevices`) - both refer to the same object. Why is there `"amount"` in the `device` object? Is this supposed to act as a cart with limited quantities?

Comment: "amount" is number of devices which user will be able to select for a particular entity and yes, devices can be chosen repeatedly. Apparently, being new to Angular definitely causes me confusion for certain concepts but with help of nice guys like yourself, I learn something once in a while :). I still need to clear my head about certain concepts for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict between two `item` variable

1. `item` in `ng-repeat`.
2. `item` model in `select` box

you can change the select box model

ex :

```
<select 
id="deviceList_{{$index}}"
name="deviceList_name_{{$index}}"
ng-model="item1"                         
....
</select>
```

and change `ng-show` to

```
<div id="device-options" ng-show="item1.id > -1">
```

here is the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hay8cmn9/)

Comment: Great! makes sense and thank you very much Sir :), I am new to Angular so it was really a good help. So 'item1' actually is given by Angular to the app itself?

Comment: actually not, `item1` just a `$scope` variable we defined and  value of `item1` holds the select box selected value. it's glad to help u with your first question. :)

Comment: I am still wondering. We did not define item1 anywhere but item only, which I assume should be available inside ng-repeat section.

Comment: If we define `ng-model` that variable put in to the `$scope` and can be access with in the controller.